# How Yarn manages package.json and bower.json files, when both are present in my project's root folder?

Tags: angularjs, yarnpkg

In my project's root folder,both **bower.json** and **package.json** are present.

When using **npm** previosly,i do both npm and bower install seperately.Now i switched to **Yarn**.My question is, what happens when i do a yarn install?

> Will all the dependencies from package.json and bower.json will get
>   installed?

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yarn decided to drop Bower support for now. Yarn won't look at your bower.json. You will need to do `bower install` aside from `yarn`.

https://bower.io/blog/2016/using-bower-with-yarn/

Answer (score 0):

A newer article https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/ explains on how to move your dependencies from bower to Yarn

The tool [bower-away](https://github.com/sheerun/bower-away) mentioned in the article will convert your `bower.json` contents to a `package.json` format (may need to run a few times to resolve all the dependencies) and this can then be installed with Yarn/npm/...

From what I understand, Yarn still doesn't look at `bower.json`

If you're like me and have npm packages installed in a different directory to bower packages, you can try `npm install --prefix` or `yarn install --modules-folder`. For Yarn, the folder used will be a replacement of `node_modules`, but make sure to have a read of https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1684